# Get access_token if you have id_token MSAL

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-msal

I'm using MSAL lib for authorize my SPA.
Init:

`msUserAgent = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(idApp, null, null, {});`

Call loginPopup:

```
msUserAgent.loginPopup(['user.read'])
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

after set my credentials, popUp not closing, but redirect to main page. Then and catch not called at all.
Issue on github about this: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/174

After redirect, my URL (in popup) has id_token (jwt-token), but this page doesn't have initialized `msUserAgent` yet. It dynamically process, I initialize  `msUserAgent` after user click (idApp getting from backend)

Question:
***Can I get access_token when I have id_token (jwt-token) by using MSAL lib?***

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so, but you should be able to use its acquireToken function to get a token with a hidden iframe that uses the user's active session with AAD.

Comment: I tried but receive error `user_login_error|User login is required`, I need to have `_user` object in `msUserAgent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for getting access_token need to do next:

1. On page where you are being redirected. You need to have loaded MSAL script
2. msUserAgent need to auto init after all scripts will be loaded
3. MSAL checking  if JWT token present in uri (after redirect), and if it exists, immediately send silent request and get access_token and save to sessionStorage (you can change to localStorage in options)